# Программа на си для вычисления ряда с заданной точностью

Tags: c, математика, ряды

Здравствуйте, нуждаюсь в помощи.
Нужно составить программу для вычисления суммы членов ряда, используя заданную точность, ряд Лейбница

[image: Ряд Лейбница с википедии]

Например, используя точность(eps)=0.2, сумма членов ряда равна=1-1\3+1\5;

У меня есть программа для иного ряда, что подходит для вычисления малых значений логарифма(достаточная точность для диапазона (0.0;1.0);

[image: Ряд с работающей программой]

```
    #include <stdio.h>      //директивы препроцессора
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{   
  //описание переменных
float x, s, f, x_nach, x_kon, delta_x, eps, temp;
int n;

printf("\nВвод исходных данных:\n");    //ввод исходных данных
printf("\nx_nach=");                        
scanf("%f", &x_nach);           //начальное значение аргумента
printf("\nx_kon=");                     
scanf("%f", &x_kon);            //конечное значение аргумента
printf("\ndelta_x=");                       
scanf("%f", &delta_x);          //шаг изменения аргумента
printf("\neps=");                       
scanf("%f", &eps);                                  //точность вычислений

//эхо-печать
printf("\nДля  x=%5.3f  до  %5.3f  с шагом  %5.3f  и точностью  %5.3f\n", x_nach, x_kon, delta_x, eps);

printf("\n   x      n         s            f");
printf("\n--------------------------------------");

x = x_nach;

do              //внешний цикл - изменение аргумента
{
    temp = (x-1.0)/(x+1.0); //первое слагаемое
    s = temp;       //начальное значение суммы
    n = 1;      //количество итераций на каждом шаге
    f = log(x); //точное значение функции

        //внутренний цикл - вычисление суммы ряда
while (fabs(temp) > eps)
    {
        //очередное слагаемое
temp *=  ((x-1.0)*(x-1.0))/((2.0*n+1.0)*(x+1.0)*(x+1.0));   
        s += temp;  //очередная сумма
        n++;            //количество итераций   
    }
    s=2.0*s;
    printf("\n%5.3f     %d     %0.6f     %0.6f", x, n, s, f);

    x += delta_x;   //увеличение аргумента на шаг  delta_x
  }
  while (x <= x_kon);

 printf("\n--------------------------------------");

return 0;
```

}

Дело в том, что я просто не знаю как записать схожую программу, вычисляющую с определенной точностью, используя данные члены, хоть и выглядит довольно просто

Comment: Что Вам не понятно? Берете из исходной программы входной и выходной блок и переписываете цикл. А вот цикл на этом форуме за Вас никто делать не будет. Поэтому есть смысл раскинуть мозгами и начать делать самому. Или лишь после этого (если не выходит) можно на форуме задать вопрос, что не выходит. В противном случае получите ответ, который решает Вашу проблему, но вряд ли Вы сиожете им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да все очень просто

```
int main()
{
    double sum = 0.0, eps = 1e-8;
    for(unsigned long n = 0; n < 0.5/eps; ++n)
        sum += (n%2 ? -1.0 : 1.0)/(2.0*n+1.0);
    printf("%.10lf\n",sum*4);
}
```

Только вот толку мало от того, что вам дают готовое решение...

Comment: Тогда зачем даёте?

Comment: @edem К вечеру воскресенья расслабленный и взаимовежливый :)

Comment: Но ведь и я получил свои законные минусы за свой вопрос здесь)

Comment: Касательно вашего кода: он не работает при точности 0.2, что поделать, просто мне нужно было через scanf задать eps (как было в коде другой задачи выше) и на основе этого вывести данные + у вас лишнее умножение суммы на 4, это не нужно, а так да, в остальном ваша программа работает

Comment: Там же очень маленькая программа, ввод,  формула, цикл, вывод, у меня проблема только с заданием цикла для точности, видимо придется все же самому делать все)

Comment: Я на 4 умножил, чтоб сразу "Пи" увидеть :) Ну, а не дописать считывание `scanf` самостоятельно - это уж, простите...